# $F\left(\mathbf r, \frac{1}{i}\nabla\right)\psi$ and $F(i\nabla, \mathbf k)\phi$ are FT's of each other if $\psi$ and $\phi$ are FT's of each other?

Tags: fourier-transform, mathematics

I'm reading Merzbacher's *Quantum Mechanics* and he states the above (for analytic $F$).
To prove this, I could come up with the following, but am not sure if the last step is quite correct.

We have
\begin{align}
F(i\nabla_{\mathbf k'}, \mathbf k)\Big|_{\mathbf k}\left\{ \phi(\mathbf k') \right\}
&= \frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3/2}} \int \psi(\mathbf r)\; F(i\nabla_{\mathbf k'}, \mathbf k)\Big|_{\mathbf k} \left\{ e^{-i\mathbf{k'\cdot r}} \right\}~\mathrm d^3r\\
&= \frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3/2}}\int \psi(\mathbf r)\; F(\mathbf r, \mathbf k) e^{-i\mathbf{k\cdot r}}~\mathrm d^3r,\\
\end{align}
where in the first step, I used that $\phi$ is the FT of $\psi$.

Now,
\begin{alignat}{4}
\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3/2}} \int F(i\nabla_{\mathbf k'}, \mathbf k)\Big|_{\mathbf k}\left\{ 
\phi(\mathbf k') \right\} e^{i\mathbf{k\cdot r}}~ \mathrm d^3k
&= \frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^3} &&\int \psi(\mathbf r')\; F(\mathbf r', \mathbf k)\; e^{i\mathbf{k\cdot (r-r')}}~ \mathrm d^3k\; \mathrm d^3r'\\
&= \frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^3} &&\int\left[ F\left(\mathbf r', \frac{1}{i}\nabla_{\mathbf r''}\right)\Bigg|_{\mathbf r} \left\{ \psi(\mathbf r') e^{i\mathbf{k\cdot (r''-r')}} \right\} \right]~ \mathrm d^3 k\; \mathrm d^3 r'\\
&= &&\int F\left(\mathbf r', \frac{1}{i}\nabla_{\mathbf r''}\right)\Bigg|_{\mathbf r} \left\{ \psi(\mathbf r')\; \delta^3(\mathbf{r''-r'}) \right\}~ \mathrm d^3r',\\
\end{alignat}

where in the second equality I used that $F(\mathbf r', \mathbf k)\; e^{i\mathbf{k\cdot r}} = F(\mathbf r', \frac{1}{i}\nabla_{\mathbf r''})\Big|_{\mathbf r} \left\{ e^{i\mathbf{k\cdot r''}} \right\}$.

**Question:** Can I now just say that the RHS equals $$F\left(\mathbf r'', \frac{1}{i}\nabla_{\mathbf r''}\right)\Bigg|_{\mathbf r} \left\{ \psi(\mathbf r'') \right\} = \left[F\left(\mathbf r, \frac{1}{i} \nabla\right)\psi\right](\mathbf r),$$ completing my proof?

---

**Edit:** As pointed by Valter in his comments, $F$ should be such that there are no commutativity issues, for instance between $\nabla_{\mathbf k'}$ and $\mathbf k'$.

Comment: Without a definition of $f(A,B)$ when A and B do not commute, it is difficult to say anything...

Comment: @ValterMoretti $F$ is just a function from $\text{position-space }\times\mathbf k\text{-space}$. No operators involved.

Comment: What it is wrong  is that $F(i\nabla_{k'},k)|_{k} \phi(k) = F(i\nabla_k,k)\phi(k)$, just because $\nabla_k$ and $k$ do not commute. So actually what you are proving is a statement different from the one in the title of your post.

Comment: Consider $F(x,p)=xp$. It seems obvious the meaning of $F(x, \nabla) = x\nabla$. However $F(x,p)=px$, but $\nabla x\neq x\nabla$ as operators..

Comment: you should first make precise a definition of $F(r,\nabla_r)$ before starting with the proof of a statement regarding those operators.

Comment: Why do you say 'no operators involved' ? Operators are explicitly involved in your statement: $F(r,i^{-1}\nabla_r)$ is an operator.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Oh yes, it is indeed an operator. And I got what you're saying why the form of $F$ must be specified since commutativity might be an issue.

Comment: But suppose that $F$ is so defined that commutativity is not an issue. Then can you say anything? :)

Comment: But the issue does exist!  “Ex falso quodlibet”

Comment: @ValterMoretti What I'm saying is that suppose that $F$ doesn't contain such "incompatible" terms like $xp_x$. Then can you say anything?

Comment: The only possibility is that F is the sum of two indipendent functions one of x and the other of p. In that case what you wrote is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot Valter for confirming! :) Can you finally just, if possible, explain why one can exploit the Dirac-delta integral here, cuz in the integral $F$ too depends on the integration variable $\mathbf r'$, so it appears to me that we can't simply pull $F$ out of the integral and exploit the Dirac-delta integral with what remains.

Comment: That is the crucial passage I think to be disputable If F is generic. If F is a sum of two independent  functions as I said above, you can check the two cases separately where everything is almost obvious and finally you can sum the results...

Comment: But there can also be terms like $xp_y$ for which too commutativity is *not* an issue...

Comment: Right, decomposing the measure as a product of measures and the Dirac Delta as a product of Deltas in the corresponding variables everything should be computed easily